# How innodb calculate key length for indexes?

Tags: mariadb, innodb

I am trying to add a combined index for 3 columns but facing an error max key length is 767 bytes, but I can't figure out how it's calculated so that I can understand in the future.

Innodb version: 5.6

Information about columns:

```
USER_ID bigint(20) utf8_general_ci
TYPE varchar(31) utf8_general_ci
REQ_NAME varchar(256) utf8_general_ci
```

`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX IDX_USER_ID_TYPE_REQ_NAME (USER_ID, TYPE, REQ_NAME)`
and it fails with  `max key length is 767 bytes`

After  `ALTER TABLE MODIFY column REQ_NAME VARCHAR(255)`  error does not appear as a result it does not fail with varchar(255) but I don't understand why, if 255 * 3 + 31 * 3 > 767. Can someone explain how it is calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 767 applies to *each* column independently.  The combined max is something else (perhaps about 8K??)

```
BIGINT -- 8 bytes
VARCHAR(n) utf8 (in 5.6) -- 2 (for length) + 3*n, with max of 767
```

Georg left off two 2's for varchar lengths.

The default was changed in 5.7 to allow for utf8mb4 by changing from 767 to 3072.  Meanwhile, see this for five workarounds for the 767 issue:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: thanks for the link, we are using a prefix for a now to avoid an issue. So in my case each column calculated independently instead of combining, the example(8 + (31 + 255) * 3 = 866) that Georg showed?

Comment: @Max - True.  You hit the problem because of "256"; "255" would have worked with `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

utf8 maps to ut8mb3, which means one code point will use 3 bytes.
bigint is a 64-bit integer (and therefore doesn't have a character set), which is 8 byte long.

8 + (31 + 255) * 3 = 866, which is too large, since due to your innodb_page_size setting the maximum index length is limited to 768 bytes.

If you need larger indexes, you have to change the global server variable `innodb_page_size`. On your server it is currently 4KB, changing it to 8KB will allow a max. keysize of 1536 bytes, changing it to 16KB will allow a max. keysize of 3072 bytes.

Comment: But when I have 255 it does not fail, that's the question why? Even in your example, an error is expected